# Return 404error.html page in C web server

Tags: c, error-handling, webserver, html

I wrote a web server in C programming language and based on the request provided in the URL the web server retrieves the relevant web pages success fully! following is the part of the code that deals with URL requests!

```
if ( strncmp(reqline[1], "/\0", 2)==0 ) 
    reqline[1] = "/index.html";
    //If no file is specified, index.html will be opened by default  

strcpy(path, ROOT); 
strcpy(&path[strlen(ROOT)], reqline[1]); 
printf("file: %s\n", path); 

if ( (fd=open(path, O_RDONLY))!=-1 )    //If a html file is found
{
    send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17, 0); 
    while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 ) 
        write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
}
else { //If html file not found
    write (clients[n], "File not found", 15);      
}
```

I want to display my `404error.html` web page (found in the folder which has index.html and other html web pages) web page when the user provides a URL of a non existing html file instead  of the text "File not found" which is currently displayed!

Comment: Why should it be different from the way you are doing for `index.html`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Because index.html is default (if no url is given)

Comment: What does it matter? You want to read a file and send it to the client. You already have this sequence in your code.

Comment: Exactly. If you can send the file requested, you can send another such as `404error.html` that informs error 404. After you can do that, you could be more sophisticated and create a `404error.html` on the fly to echo the file name that was requested.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried todo like index.html but it  did not work :(

Comment: Then you need to understand *why* it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try making the client request `404error.html`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I am not sure! can you correct in my code?

Comment: @KushanPeiris you're saying that a version of your code which you haven't shown doesn't do what you expect. You need to show that code, not something which does what you don't want it to do, but presumably *does* work.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not sure"? Try making a request from the client for file `404error.html`. Your code has a gap, not an error. Oh-- the "gap" was poor formatting and unnecessary whitespace, that has been edited.

Comment: @WeatherVane I havent created a such a request for index.html :O so why do I need to create for error404.html?

Comment: Is it really *your* code?

Comment: "File not found" shouldn't that be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n" and then the 404 file?

Comment: @NeilEdelman Thanx how can I adjust my code for that?

Comment: So are you saying the server only serves up `index.html` and not any other file on demand?

Comment: It serves Index.html and other html files in my folder! I want to return the error404.html in the same folder if the html page in the request given does not  exist :O

Comment: For heaven's sake! Just replace the `else` part with the same as in the `if` part with `else if ( (fd=open("404error.html", O_RDONLY))!=-1 ) ` and so on, where `404error.html` is in a visible location. This wasn't *your* code, was it? You copied it, but don't understand it. BTW don't forget to close the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane First part I did by myself but when it comes to URL part I had to read some blogs but couldn't understand

Comment: @WeatherVane Is a great help if you can correct my code because I did not understand what you said

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you wrote this code, but can't figure out how to return 404 page. It seems like it wasn't you who wrote the code, and now you are asked to add more functionality to it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't compile or run the incomplete code, but a "guess" would be to send the error notification file if the requested file is not found. The "404error.html" file must exist on an available path.

```
if ( (fd=open(path, O_RDONLY))!=-1 ) {                  // If the file is found
    send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17, 0); 
    while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 ) 
        write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
    close(fd);                                          // add this
}
else if ( (fd=open("404error.html", O_RDONLY))!=-1 ) {  // Send the error file
    send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17, 0); 
    while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 ) 
        write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
    close(fd);                                          // add this
}
else {
    write (clients[n], "File not found", 15);           // tough luck, back to to you
}
```

I don't know what `clients[n]` is, but am sure you do.

The source code could be more efficient by not repeating the transmission code but I leave that to you. This answer is an idea.

Answer (score 1):

But I don't know what `write` and `send` do in your implementation, but one should always abide by HTTP,

> Response = Status-Line
>   *(( general-header
>   | response-header
>   | entity-header ) CRLF)
>   CRLF
>   [ message-body ]

From status codes at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html. This is a promising C coded model, http://tinyhttpd.sourceforge.net/. Specifically, what's wrong with your http response in general, as I can see it,

```
if ( (fd=open(path, O_RDONLY))!=-1 )    //If a html file is found
{
    send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n\n", 17, 0); 
}
else { //If html file not found
    send(clients[n], "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n", 20, 0);
    fd = fd_404; // assumes fd_404 is always open
}
while ( (bytes_read=read(fd, data_to_send, BYTES))>0 ) 
    write (clients[n], data_to_send, bytes_read);
// rewind or close the file . . .
```